# rc-ranger - properly handling range values

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the value of [rc-slider](https://github.com/schrodinger/rc-slider)'s values as they change. I can't get the slider to move smoothly across while at the same time, keeping its value up to date. Any ideas?
Here's link to a work example in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/myyr1xw1jj

```
<Range id="price-slider"
          style={{ margin: "40px 10px 20px 10px" }}
          min={this.state.sliderMin}
          max={this.state.sliderMax}
          defaultValue={[this.state.sliderMin, this.state.sliderMax]}
          tipFormatter={value => `\$${value}`}
          step={50}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onSliderChange}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to move this code

```
const createSliderWithTooltip = Slider.createSliderWithTooltip;
const Range = createSliderWithTooltip(Slider.Range);
```

Out of the render() method

Its because every time the value changes it creates the new instance of the `range`.

Here is the example of it: https://codesandbox.io/s/xvmry3n70z